# Mongo DB query - take the latest one and group results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have such document structure

```
{
  lang: en,
  origin: 'Origin Value',
  key: 'Key',
  translation: 'Translated value',
  createdAt: <date>
}
```

So there is various number of languages (en, de, it etc) and there are a lot of key's duplication with different date (createdAt field). I need to construct a query, which will take the latest localisation for each key for each language and group it by lang.

Expected result:

```
{
  en: [
    {
      origin: 'Origin Value',
      key: 'Key',
      translation: 'Translated value',
      createdAt: <the latest one date for this particular key>     
    },
    {
      origin: 'Second Origin Value',
      key: 'Second Key',
      translation: 'Second Translated value',
      createdAt: <the latest one date for this particular key>     
    }
    ...
  ],
  de: [...],
  it: [...],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run on mongo shell V2.6.4

```
var cursor = db.c.aggregate([ {
    $sort : {
        // sort to make sure the latest document of every group (lang, key) is at
        // first location.
        createAt : -1
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            lang : "$lang",
            key : "$key"
        },
        doc : {
            $first : "$$ROOT" // current entire document
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id.lang", // regroup to combine all keys into one lang
        body : {
            $push : {
                orgin : "$doc.origin",
                key : "$doc.key",
                translation : "$doc.translation",
                createAt : "$doc.createAt"
            }
        }
    }
} ]);

var result = {}; // store final result
cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    result[doc._id] = doc.body; // aggregation pipeline can not process on key,
                                // this is a way to convert data to your
                                // expected format
});
```

If you run mongo shell before V2.6, consider this way at the last statement:

```
cursor.result.forEach(function(doc) {
    result[doc._id] = doc.body; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work for you somehow, so first sort the results by created at and retrieve the first result for each group using $first operator:

```
db.dictionary.aggregate(
{$sort: {createdAt:-1}}, 
{$group: {_id:{lang: "$lang", key:"$key"}, createdAt:{$first:"$createdAt"}, origin: {$first:"$origin"}, translation: {$first:"$translation"}}})
```

Btw as far as I understood you can not have dynamic field names in aggregation framework so you can't have language key as field names in your output.

Comment: I think it's incorrect to use `{$group: {_id:"$key", lang:{$first: "$lang"}, createdAt:{$first:"$createdAt"}, origin: {$first:"$origin"}, translation: {$first:"$translation"}}}`. Because after this processing, each **key** will has only one **lang**, but actually it's possible to several **lang**.

Comment: You are correct; the group id needs to be key and lang such as in the second query

Comment: Thanks guys, I haven't fully resolved my problem, but have enough information for further investigation. Will attach final result if I have such :)